# Embeddable proxy server in java

Tags: java, ajax, http, selenium, proxy

For my selenium automation project i want to know whether any ajax calls are running, before i click on any element. So I want to run a embedded proxy server as part of automation code and guide all HTTP traffic through the proxy server, so that i can query the proxy server for number running ajax calls. But i did not find any embeddable proxy servers in java. Below are the features i am looking for.

- Should be embeddable HTTP/HTTPS proxy server.
- Should notify me before/after it sends/receives data to/from remote server.
- I should be able to read the contents before/after it sends/receives data.

[FiddlerCore](http://fiddler.wikidot.com/fiddlercore) API provides me all these features, but it is for .net(I don't want to use JNI or bridges). Are there any such proxy servers in java?

Comment: How about [Browsermob Proxy](http://bmp.lightbody.net/)?

Comment: Just gone through Browsermob Proxy page. Looks promising. Thanks for the suggestion.